# Is it possible to use a variable I've got from an .onclick event function, and use it outside said event, in another part of the code?

Tags: javascript, function, events, onclick, click

I'm learning JavaScript, and I'm making a simple project where I have a form (with `name`, `lastname`, and `age`) and a button.

I want the user to fill the form, and press the button. After that I want to use the `.onclick` event to store all the info in an array.
Then I want to create another button that when I pressed it shows a list of all the names, lastnames and ages from this array.

The problem is, the array I create inside the .onclick event function can't be used outside of said function. Am I doing something wrong or is it impossible to do that?
Here's part of my code:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input"); //id of the button i want to press to fill my array
var ver = document.getElementById("ver"); //id of the button i want to press to show my array
var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
var i = 0;
var lista = new Array(100); //Array va con mayuscula!!!

input.onclick = function() {
  var listaFinal = CrearArreglo(lista, i);
  i++; //lo sumo aca porque sino en la funcion se pierde el valor
}

function CrearArreglo(miLista, j) {
  var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  var apellido = document.getElementById("apellido").value;
  var edad = document.getElementById("edad").value;

  miLista[j] = {
    name: nombre,
    lastname: apellido,
    age: edad
  };
  return miLista;
}

// This is the part that I have trouble with, since I get an error that says "Uncaught ReferenceError: listaFinal is not defined"
resultado.innerHTML = listaFinal[0].name;
```

```css
#contenedor {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 60px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #D05353;
  background-color: #E58F65;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 65px;
}

#input {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  background-color: #35A7FF;
  border-color: #82DDF0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Ejercicio 2</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #F1E8B8">
  <div id="contenedor">
    Nombre:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="Nombre" maxlength="20" id="nombre">
    <br> Apellido:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="Apellido" maxlength="20" id="apellido">
    <br> Edad:
    <br>
    <input type="number" name="Edad" id="edad">
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="input">Ingresar</button>
  </div>

  <button type="button" id="ver">Ver Lista</button>
  <br>
  <div id="resultado"></div>

  <script src="javascript2.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please post the html as well!

Comment: `var listaFinal ...` by using `var` here you make it a local variable, remove the `var` from that line, and add `var listaFinal;` to a higher common scope

Comment: Ok! i just edited my post and made it more readable lol, im gonna try making that variable a global one! thanks everyone!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define `listaFinal` as Global variable and modify its value in function:

```
var listaFinal=[];

input.onclick = function() { 
 listaFinal=CrearArreglo(lista,i);
}
//Use it when modified
```

```js
var input=document.getElementById("input"); //id of the button i want to press to fill my array
var ver=document.getElementById("ver");  //id of the button i want to press to show my array
var resultado=document.getElementById("resultado"); 
var i=0;
var lista= new Array(100);//Array va con mayuscula!!!
var listaFinal =[];
input.onclick = function() {
 listaFinal=CrearArreglo(lista,i);
 i++; //lo sumo aca porque sino en la funcion se pierde el valor
}

function CrearArreglo(miLista,j){
 var nombre=document.getElementById("nombre").value;
 var apellido=document.getElementById("apellido").value;
 var edad=document.getElementById("edad").value;

 miLista[j]={name:nombre, lastname:apellido, age:edad};
 return miLista;
}
function newFunction(){
    resultado.innerHTML=listaFinal[0].name;
}
/*this is the part that i have trouble with, since i get an error that says "Uncaught ReferenceError: listaFinal is not defined"*/
```

```css
#contenedor{
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 60px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #D05353;
  background-color: #E58F65;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 65px;
}

#input{
 width: 50%;
 height: 50px;
 margin-left: 30px;
 background-color: #35A7FF;
 border-color: #82DDF0;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <title>Ejercicio 2</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #F1E8B8">
<div id="contenedor">
 Nombre:
 <br>
 <input type="text" name="Nombre" maxlength="20" id="nombre">
 <br>
 Apellido:
 <br>
 <input type="text" name="Apellido" maxlength="20" id="apellido">
 <br>
 Edad:
 <br>
 <input type="number" name="Edad" id="edad">
 <br>
 <br>
 <button type="button" id="input">Ingresar</button>
</div>

<button type="button" id="ver">Ver Lista</button>
<br>
<div id="resultado"></div>
<button onclick="newFunction()">Another button</button>
<script src="javascript2.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I edited my post so now it's more clear for you guys. I tried what you and others suggested, but wouldnt i be creating an array of an array? I edited my code but it won't recognize the listaFinal.name value of the array.

Comment: You are using `listaFinal` variable when it has no value. Means you should write this code in onclick function `resultado.innerHTML=listaFinal[0].name;`

Comment: yes that would work but i want to show my array when clicking another button, not the same one i use to load my array. The reason i use the "resultado.innerHTML=listaFinal[0].name" .- and not when i click another button is because i want to make sure it works first, then i'll create another button and put the resultado.innerHTML=listaFinal[0].name; inside it

Comment: Yes that's why we are using global variables. See updated answer for more details...

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Ritesh's solution, but you don't even need to create this global variable. You can just add it to the function, and access it through input.onclick (like input.onclick.listFinal)

```
input.onclick = function() { 
 this.listFinal=CrearArreglo(lista,i);
}
```

Comment: It says :"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" . When you want to use the value from listaFinal, do you call it like this? resultado.innerHTML= input.onclick.listaFinal[0];

Comment: _"like `input.onclick.listFinal`"_, no just `input.listFinal` so would use `input.listFinal[0]`. Though personally I wouldn't pollute the html input object itself with arbitrary data.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your variable outside of the `onclick` function, your `onclick` function will refer to the variable outside the function:

```
var listaFinal;

input.onclick = function() {
    listaFinal = CrearArreglo(lista, i);
    ...
};

resultado.innerHTML = listaFinal[0].name;
```

Comment: They would also need to remove the `var` keyword from the appropriate line inside the function, otherwise it will remain scoped to just that function.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? Is there something wrong with what I said?

Answer (score -1):

You can declare `var listaFinal` outside of the function scope.

and then reassign it inside of the function:

```
listaFina = crearrArreglo()
```

Comment: Since you say it is naive, you might want to describe why and possibly add an alternative.